# jython 2.5 can't print string

Tags: jython

```
Jython 2.5.2 (Release_2_5_2:7206, Mar 2 2011, 23:12:06)
[Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (Sun Microsystems Inc.)] on java1.6.0_20
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print 3
3
>>> print "3"
...
```

I tried version Jython 2.2.1, it was ok, but the problem remains in version Jython 2.7b1:

```
Jython 2.7b1 (default:ac42d59644e9, Feb 9 2013, 15:24:52)
[Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (Sun Microsystems Inc.)] on java1.6.0_39
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print 'ab'
...
```

Comment: are you sure you haven't typed `print '3"` or `print "3'` (mismatched quotes)?

Comment: Please put a little effort into your question ...

Comment: Sorry. After some work, may be a bug for 2.5.2

Comment: Maybe this answer will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17793767/407651.

Comment: @mzjn:I have tried the standalone version, my jre version is 1.6, the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and my version works good:

```
Jython 2.5.3 (2.5:c56500f08d34+, Aug 13 2012, 14:48:36)
[Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (Oracle Corporation)] on java1.7.0_09
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print 3
3
>>> print "3"
3
```

I use more recent versions of both Jython and Java, but I think this is not problem in your case. Try to save those `print` statements in `print_test.py` file and execute it via `jython print_test.py` and with CPython `python print_test.py`. Show us results.

Answer (score 0):

same problem here:

```
Jython 2.5.2 (Release_2_5_2:7206, Mar 2 2011, 23:12:06)
[Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (Oracle Corporation)] on java1.7.0_02
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print 'hi'
...
```

Looks like just a bug for 2.5.2

Comment: but problem remains in Jython 2.7b1

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is specific to the OS or machine environment, as it behaves for me on windows in 2.7.0 and have seen it behave in previous versions.

```
Jython 2.7.0 (default:9987c746f838, Apr 29 2015, 02:25:11)
[Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (Oracle Corporation)] on java1.7.0_51
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import platform
>>> platform.platform()
'Java-1.7.0_51-Java_HotSpot-TM-_64-Bit_Server_VM,_24.51-b03,_Oracle_Corporation-on-Windows_7-6.1-amd64'
>>> print 3
3
>>> print '3'
3
>>> print "3"
3
```

What is the underlying OS and how are you invoking the console? Do you have the problem with constructs other than print or when not referencing a quoted string?